# Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find

This Function in a workbook used to work. It was finding, in another workbook, a range on a Item Master worksheet in column A:A and returning a range for the Part found.

The `Set FindRow` now fails with a popup saying subscript out of range. Clicking Help provides some information but I haven't been able to apply it here. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
Function FindPartNumber(ByVal Part As String, ByVal mpl_wb As Workbook) As Range

    Dim FindRow As Range

    Set FindRow = mpl_wb.Worksheets("Item Master").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Part, _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   MatchCase:=True)
    If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then
        Set FindPartNumber = FindRow
    Else
        Set FindPartNumber = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try validating both function parameters, and checking the returned object for `Nothing`

The top `Sub` is a test illustrating how to check the return type of the `Function`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestPart()

    Dim result As Range

    Set result = FindPartNumber(123, ThisWorkbook)    'Make sure that "result" is Set

    If Not result Is Nothing Then Debug.Print result.Address  'Check result object

End Sub
```

---

```
'If String/Workbook params are missing, or part is not found, this returns "Nothing"

Public Function FindPartNumber(ByVal part As String, ByVal mplWb As Workbook) As Range

    Dim findRow As Range, ws As Worksheet

    If mplWb Is Nothing Or Len(part) = 0 Then Exit Function    'Invalid file (mplWb)

    With mplWb
        On Error Resume Next   'Expected error: sheet name not found (sheet doesn't exist)
        Set ws = .Worksheets("Item Master")
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            With ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

                Set findRow = .Find(What:=part, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    MatchCase:=True)

                If Not findRow Is Nothing Then Set FindPartNumber = findRow

            End With
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

.

**Note**

To make the function more generic (reusable), move all hard-coded parts outside

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestPart()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, result As Range, searchRange As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Item Master")

    Set searchRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    Set result = FindPartNumber(123, searchRange)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then Debug.Print result.Address
End Sub
```

---

```
'If String/Range params are missing, or part is not found, this returns "Nothing"

Public Function FindPartNumber(ByVal part As String, ByVal rng As Range) As Range

    Dim findRow As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Or Len(part) = 0 Then Exit Function  'Invalid search range or part

    Set findRow = rng.Find(What:=part, _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                           MatchCase:=True)

    If Not findRow Is Nothing Then Set FindPartNumber = findRow

End Function
```

Comment: Works great, the organized structure allowed me to find the cause of the problem. It's when the Part is not found, the function now generates "Object variable or With block variable not set" error on End Function. I did use the Option Explicit, no compile errors, everything is Dim As. Seems like FindRow being Nothing is the problem? Not sure how to solve it though.

Comment: @Rab - then the problem is just surfacing in the function, but is caused by the line of code calling this function: it sends an empty string as the "Part" id (not sure what's causing that)

Comment: The part is populated and not empty but the part is not found by 
 FindRow because it might be old or mistyped and not in ws.Range. This leaves FindRow as Nothing never Seting FindPartNumber with a range and the function returns throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, in that case the function returns `Nothing` and the other code is expecting a `Range`; you can make the function return a certain range in case the part is not found

Comment: Thank you, great suggestions. I also added some user messaging to help. I am on my way again.